# Update a recipe that was previously based on master branch but now is released with version

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

I have a recipe [canboat](https://github.com/shantanoo-desai/meta-canboat/blob/master/recipes-support/canboat/canboat.bb) which was previously based on no official release version and was based on the `SRCREV` on the `master` branch.

#### `canboat.bb`

```
SUMMARY = "CANBOAT- A small but effective set of command-line utilities to work with CAN networks on BOATs."
SECTION = "base"
LICENSE = "GPLv3"

DEPENDS += "libxslt-native canboat-native"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://GPL;md5=05507c6da2404b0e88fe5a152fd12540"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/canboat/canboat.git;branch=${SRCBRANCH} \
           file://0001-Do-not-use-root-user-group-during-install.patch \
           file://0001-Define-ANALYZEREXEC.patch \
           file://0001-use-php-instead-of-php5.patch \
          "
SRCBRANCH = "master"
SRCREV = "93b2ebfb334d7a9750b6947d3a4af9b091be2432"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

PREFIX ?= "${root_prefix}"
#PREFIX_class-native = "${prefix}"

EXTRA_OEMAKE_append_class-target = " ANALYZEREXEC=analyzer "

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake
}
do_install() {
   oe_runmake DESTDIR=${D} PREFIX=${root_prefix} EXEC_PREFIX=${exec_prefix} install

}

RDEPENDS_${PN}_append_class-target = " php-cli perl"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

The [main repository](https://github.com/canboat/canboat) did a release officially a couple of days ago and I want to update my recipe to point to `v.1.0.0`.

#### Workflow

1. I used `devtool add canboat [link-tar-ball]`
2. copied the changes in the original `canboat.bb`
3. changed the name of the recipe to `canboat_1.0.0.bb` since the recipe now has `${PV}` for fetching the right version

#### Updated recipe

only the `SRC_URI` now pointing to the `.tar.gz` is and the `md5sum`s have been updated.

```
SUMMARY = "CANBOAT- A small but effective set of command-line utilities to work with CAN networks on BOATs."
SECTION = "base"
LICENSE = "GPLv3"

DEPENDS += "libxslt-native canboat-native"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://GPL;md5=05507c6da2404b0e88fe5a152fd12540"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/canboat/canboat.git;branch=${SRCBRANCH} \
           file://0001-Do-not-use-root-user-group-during-install.patch \
           file://0001-Define-ANALYZEREXEC.patch \
           file://0001-use-php-instead-of-php5.patch \
          "
SRC_URI = "https://github.com/canboat/canboat/archive/v${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "6ee6162d30faa3b3f1ff068cc7a70a60"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "6bf1050a83a5d7eb8351547c10e7e2ae2e1811250d50a63880074f0c07ec672e"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

PREFIX ?= "${root_prefix}"
#PREFIX_class-native = "${prefix}"

EXTRA_OEMAKE_append_class-target = " ANALYZEREXEC=analyzer "

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake
}
do_install() {
   oe_runmake DESTDIR=${D} PREFIX=${root_prefix} EXEC_PREFIX=${exec_prefix} install

}

RDEPENDS_${PN}_append_class-target = " php-cli perl"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

I tried `bitbake -k canboat` to check the build process

#### Error

I get a QA error as following:

```
 QA Issue: canboat-native: LIC_FILES_CHKSUM points to an invalid file: 
/home/des/Yocto/PHYTEC_BSPs/yocto_fsl/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/canboat-native/1.0.0-r0/git/GPL
```

I tried going into the above mentioned folder and there was no `GPL` file there on the contrary the file is present in the `canboat_1.0.0` folder.

The structure is as follows:

```
.
├── canboat-1.0.0
│   ├── actisense-serial
│   ├── airmar
│   ├── analyzer
│   ├── candump2analyzer
│   ├── common
│   ├── config
│   ├── group-function
│   ├── ip
│   ├── n2kd
│   ├── nmea0183
│   ├── samples
│   ├── send-message
│   ├── socketcan-writer
│   └── util
├── git
└── temp
```

and the `git` folder has nothing in it.

#### Question

How do I overcome the `QA` test and is there a better way to update the recipes?

Comment: You don't need `S = "${WORKDIR}/git"` in your new recipe. When you refer specific version from tarball, yocto de-references the path using `${PN}-${PV}`

Comment: should I go ahead and remove it?

Comment: Yes, remove the `S = "${WORKDIR}/git"` alone and try re-compiling it.

Comment: Adding to that, you also don't need `do_compile` and `do_install` in your recipe.

Comment: Your suggestion for removing the folder works. I think `do_compile` and `do_install` are needed since the repo needs to be manually installed and has no autoconf. The `Makefile` is all handwritten.

Comment: Usually bitbake by default invokes make if it couldn't find autoconf/m4 related files. So for sure you don't need `do_compile`

Comment: You can write the comment as an answer and I will accept it apparently that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `S = "${WORKDIR}/git"` in your new recipe. When you refer specific version from tarball, yocto de-references the path using `${PN}-${PV}`

This is because when tarball is extracted, the source path will be `${WORKDIR}/${PN}-${PV}`.

Additionally, you can remove `do_compile` section of your recipe as Yocto by default calls `make` when it can't find `Makefile.am/in` or `autoconf` files.